# redirect 301 opencart not working

Tags: redirect, categories, opencart

Redirect 301 categories and products not working

Hello

i try many 301 redirect codes to redirect old categories and products links that indexing in google to the new seo url

but not redirect !!!

the old category like that
http://www.example.com/index.php?route= ... ry&path=65

the new
http://www.example.com/science-books

help me please

Answer (score -1):

Google will take some time to index the new URL. It may vary from couple of days to weeks.

Redirecting may not be a good idea. Be patient your new URLs will get indexed.

Comment: Yes i know google indexing but i want to redirect old urls to new